# Configuring apache 2.4 with php 5.6.32 configuring with source in linux

Tags: php-5.6, apache2.4, software-collections

I have installed httpd 2.4, downloaded .tar.gz and configured as:

```
./configure --with-apr=/tmp/apr-1.6.3 --with-apr-util=/tmp/apr-util-1.6.1 --enable-so && make && make install (my apr and apr-util are at /tmp location)
```

also I have installed php 5.6.32, downloaded tar.gz and configured as:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --enable-fpm && make && make install
```

Problem is I am unable to add the fpm handler, any direction what should I do.

Should I proceed with how its described in [redhat developer guide](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/) or [apache wiki for FPM](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM)

Thanks in advance and correcting me, if I am doing some/lots of thinh wrong :)

Comment: Which distribution are you using ?

Comment: CentOs 6.9, and probably I have identified the issue, will update soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why trying to build from sources when binary packages exists in various repositories ?

Yes the [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/) gives you correct way to use FPM (as the Apache wiki in the SetHandler way).

The linked howto is for CentOS 7, but works for CentOS 6 using the httpd24 Software Collections.

Alternative solution is to use a 3rd party repository, such as "remi", see the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

Comment: Can you please provide me a source article to install apache 2.4 with php 5.6 in FPM mode, I tried to search so, but failed

Thanks in advanced

Comment: @remi-collect, the Wizard indeed helpful, I'm loving it